# I want to replace all the spaces with "-"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to replace all the spaces with "-".

This is my code:

```py
print("enter movie name with dashes in spaces,all under case")
print("like this for example")
print("django-unchained")

b=0

a=input("enter movie name now : ")

y=input("Release year? : ")
for x in range (0,len(a)):
    if a[b].isspace():
        a[b]="-"
    b+=1
```

All it says is:

```
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: `a.replace(' ', '_')`

Comment: Strings are read-only. Operations that modify a value in place won't work on strings.

Comment: it puts dash between a and y but not in the string of a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, strings are not mutable. In other words, Python does not directly allow you to treat a string as an array of characters. When you use `a[b]`, you are retrieving the character at a specific index, not addressing the element in an array. Here are a couple options:

**Use [replace](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp)**

```
new_string = a.replace(' ', '-')
```

This is the easiest approach to get the outcome you described. If this was a simplified example and you wanted to index the array for a particular reason, try the next option.

**Convert to a [list](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp)**

```
new_list = list(a)
```

You can now modify the individual characters in the list, similar to your original approach.

Comment: you can also give `a = a.replace(' ','-')`

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are not mutable, which means they cannot be changed.

You can use `replace()` instead:

```py
a = a.replace(' ', '-')
```

Comment: if capitalising certain positions in a string is possible why not this?

Comment: @NasrUllah that too produces a new string.

Comment: capitalizing DOES NOT change the string, it returns another string, you can check it by looking into original string after capitalizing

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
a=input("enter movie name now : ").replace(" ", "-")

y= input("Release year? : ").replace(" ", "-")

print(a)
print(y)
```